# How to disable context menu option when multiple folders are selected?

Tags: windows, directory, contextmenu

This is my first question, it is bugging me for the past few weeks so thought of asking it here.

I have added a context menu option for directories by adding the below registry key.
**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\shell\Upload
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\shell\Upload\command**

The problem is, i want to show upload option if only one directory is selected. If user selects more than one directory, upload option shouldn't be displayed.

I appreciate the help.

Comment: With that registry setting, the menu entry will always be shown. You'll need to write a shell menu extension program if you need to conditionally show your menu entry.

Comment: @Jay And how do you do that...?